# AMP analytics events for scroll

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

I am trying to add analytics to my AMP page.while tra

```html
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello, AMP Analytics</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.ampproject.org/article-metadata.html" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      opacity: 0
    }
  </style><noscript><style>body {opacity: 1}</style></noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
    <script type="application/json">
      {
        "vars": {
          "account": "UA-xxxxxxxx-x"
        },
        "triggers": {
          "trackPageview": {
            "on": "visible",
            "request": "pageview"
          },
          "scrollPings": {
            "on": "scroll",
            "scrollSpec": {
              "verticalBoundaries": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
            },
            "request": "event",
            "vars": {
              "eventId": "scroll"
            }
          },
          "trackEvent": {
            "selector": "#event-test",
            "on": "click",
            "request": "event",
            "vars": {
              "eventCategory": "${canonicalUrl}",
              "eventAction": "click"
            }
          }

        }
      }
    </script>
  </amp-analytics>

  <h1 id="header">AMP Page</h1>

  <span id="event-test" class="box">
    Click here to generate an event
  </span>
  <h2>

    Page semi-protected Blog From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia "Blogger" redirects here. For the Google service with same name, see Blogger (service). For other uses, see Blog (disambiguation). Not to be confused with .blog. Journalism Simons Perskaart
    DOM.jpg News Writing style Ethics Objectivity News values Attribution Defamation Editorial independence Journalism school Index of journalism articles Areas Arts Business Data Entertainment Environment Fashion Medicine Politics Science Sports Technology
    Trade Traffic Weather World Genres Advocacy Analytic Blogging Broadcast Citizen Civic Collaborative Comics-based Community Data Database Gonzo Immersion Investigative Literary Muckraking Narrative "New Journalism" Non-profit Online Opinion Peace Photojournalism
    Scientific Sensor Underground Visual Watchdog Social impact Fake news Fourth Estate Fifth Estate Freedom of the press Infotainment Media bias Public relations Press service Propaganda model Yellow journalism News media Newspapers Magazines TV and
    radio Internet News agencies Alternative media Roles Journalists (reporters) Columnist Blogger Editor Copy editor Meteorologist News presenter Photographer Pundit / commentator Newspaper nicu buculei 01.svg Journalism portal Category: Journalism v
    t e A blog (a truncation of the expression "weblog")[1] is a discussion or informational website published on the World Wide Web consisting of discrete, often informal diary-style text entries ("posts"). Posts are typically displayed in reverse chronological
    order, so that the most recent post appears first, at the top of the web page. Until 2009, blogs were usually the work of a single individual,[citation needed] occasionally of a small group, and often covered a single subject or topic. In the 2010s,
    "multi-author blogs" (MABs) have developed, with posts written by large numbers of authors and sometimes professionally edited. MABs from newspapers, other media outlets, universities, think tanks, advocacy groups, and similar institutions account
    for an increasing quantity of blog traffic. The rise of Twitter and other "microblogging" systems helps integrate MABs and single-author blogs into the news media. Blog can also be used as a verb, meaning to maintain or add content to a blog. This
    page was last edited on 18 May 2017, at 21:34. Text is available under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License; additional terms may apply. By using this site, you agree to the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy. Wikipedia® is a registered
    trademark of the Wikimedia Foundation, Inc., a non-profit organization. Privacy policyAbout WikipediaDisclaimersContact WikipediaDevelopersCookie statementMobile viewWikimedia Foundation Powered by MediaWiki
  </h2>
</body>

</html>
```

ckPageview and trackEvent generate events. scrollPings does not.
Has anybody tries this out?
** The reference code for scrollPing is from AMP by Example page.
Thanks in advance

```js
< amp - analytics type = "googleanalytics" >
  <script type = "application/json" > {
    "vars": {
      "account": "UA-XXXXXXXX-X"
    },
    "triggers": {
      "trackPageview": {
        "on": "visible",
        "request": "pageview"
      },
      "scrollPings": {
        "on": "scroll",
        "scrollSpec": {
          "verticalBoundaries": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
        },
        "request": "event",
        "vars": {
          "eventId": "scroll"
        }
      },
      "trackEvent": {
        "selector": "#event-test",
        "on": "click",
        "request": "event",
        "vars": {
          "eventCategory": "${canonicalUrl}",
          "eventAction": "click"
        }
      }

    }
  } 
</script> 
</amp-analytics>
```

Comment: Can you show the logs returned by amp validator?

Comment: Also, could you show the entire page if it's hosted somewhere?

Comment: I have updated the entire page. Thanks

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @GuyBowden Nope

Answer (score 0):

Working with another one of our developers we managed to figure this out, at least partially. There are some URL substitute variables and you need to use the one for verticalScrollBoundary to report a percentage (like you're doing for your test event there). Please note the percent sign after the `'${verticalScrollBoundary}%'` variable is OPTIONAL and added to be consistent in our analytics report with non-AMP scroll depth tracking.

This worked for us:

```js
'scrollPings' => array(
  'on' => 'scroll',
  'request' => 'event',
  'scrollSpec' => array(
    'verticalBoundaries' => array( 0, 25, 50, 75, 100 )
  ),
  'vars' => array(
    'eventCategory' => 'AMP Scroll Depth',
    'eventAction'   => 'Scrolled',
    'eventLabel'    => '${verticalScrollBoundary}%',
  ),
),
```

Apologies, that's PHP syntax that gets translated into JSON b/c we're using the WordPress plugin. For JSON it would be (I believe):

```js
"scrollPings": {
  "on": "scroll",
  "request": "event",
  "scrollSpec": {
    "verticalBoundaries": [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]
  },
  "vars": {
    "eventCategory": "AMP Scroll Depth",
    "eventAction": "Scrolled",
    "eventLabel": "${verticalScrollBoundary}%"
  },
}
```

The one thing we haven't figured out is that it seems to be logging a null value of either "(not set)" or "%" if you include a percent sign like I have at the end of the`'${verticalScrollBoundary}%'` variable. Please note that percent sign is OPTIONAL. If there's no percent sign we just get a (not set) value being logged which doesn't seem to equate to 0 (you'll notice I've added 0 in the array of possible values).

Comment: Thanks the basic functionality seems to be working now